# how to move randomly generated object to the center of the screen in android Using LIBgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm a beginner android game programmer, I use LIBgdx

I have a playState class

```
public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);

    obj = new Objects();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, Game.WIDTH , Game.HEIGHT);       

}
@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    obj.update(dt);
}
```

I have an Objects class

```
public class Objects {
    private Vector2 posObj;
    private static final int MOVEMENT = 2;
    private Vector2 velo;
    private Texture objTx;
    private Random rand;

    private static final int FLUCTUATION = 400;

    public Objects(){

        objTX = new Texture("objies.png");
        rand = new Random();

        posObj = new Vector2(rand.nextInt(FLUCTUATION),rand.nextInt(FLUCTUATION));           

        velo = new Vector2(0, 0);

        }

public void update(float dt){

}
```

Now, What I'm tring to do is:
 Move this randomly generated object to the center of the screen and then dispose.
 Serious Help required! Thank-you

Comment: please show the code of your update method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know where your object is and you know where the middle is (Game.WIDTH/2 , Game.HEIGHT/2)

If the center is to the left of the object move it to the left, if center is above move object up etc.

So a very simple solution:

```
public void update(float delta){

    if(posObj.x < Game.WIDTH/2){
        velocity.x = MOVEMENT;
    }
    else {
        velocity.x = -MOVEMENT;
    }

    if(posObj.y < Game.HEIGHT/2){
        velocity.y = MOVEMENT;
    }
    else {
        velocity.y = -MOVEMENT;
    }

    posObj.y += velocity.y * delta;
    posObj.x += velocity.x * delta;

}
```

This might cause your object to jump around the middle without ever really hitting the exact coordinates. So you can check the distance from the object to the middle by adding this method to your object:

```
public Vector2d getPosition(){
    return posObj;
}
```

And then check for the distance:

```
if( obj.dst(Game.WIDTH , Game.HEIGHT) <= closeEnough ){
    obj = new Objects(); 
}
```

closeEnough  is a distance you set.